# It it possible for a bounded linear operator to have an immeasurable spectrum?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

And if it is, would those spectral values be continuous, discrete, or residual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectrum is always a closed set, therefore measurable.